# Wordpress: Totally different theme on Twitter mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, twitter

I have a Wordpress website and I noticed a weird behavior on Twitter. When I post a link on Twitter and tap on it on my iPhone, the website looks totally different. Like a "Reader" view. Nearly no design. And no Google Ads. I don't have that behavior when I do the same on Facebook, or use Twitter on my computer. My Wordpress theme works on the computer and on the phone. It looks a little different, but similar on the phone. As I said, on Twitter/Mobile it looks like no theme at all. I have Jetpack, but mobile theme is off there.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. It was the AMP plugin. Twitter called my link with ".../amp" at the end. Now I have the problem that it can't the page, when the plug in is disabled. But thats ok, perhaps I change the links somehow.